# Plus sign turns into blank space in Adxstudio portal's invitation code?

Tags: dynamics-crm, urlencode, adxstudio-portals

I'm developing a portal site for Dynamic CRM using Adxstudio. When I create a portal user, a background workflow will generate an invitation code, and send an email to registered email address which contains an URL to my register page.

For example, an user with invitation code `aaaaa+bbbbb+ccccc/dddd` will received the URL `https://example.com/register?invitation=aaaaa+bbbbb+ccccc/dddd`.

In the register page, I have a textbox, which will be fill automatically with the invitation in URL parameter. The problem is all plus signs are now treated as blank space. Because of that, the textbox will be `aaaaa bbbbb ccccc/dddd` instead of `aaaaa+bbbbb+ccccc/dddd`. Also since I'm using Adxstudio online, I do not have access to the page's underline code to fix this problem.

To handle this, I have thought of the following solutions:

- Encode the invitation code within send mail workflow, so that the URL will became `https://example.com/register?invitation=aaaaa%2Bbbbbb%2Bccccc%2Fdddd`. I believe this is the cleanest solution. However, CRM workflow settings does not seem to support URL encoding natively, or at least I haven't found anyway to do that, and I really don't want to write a custom workflow just for this.
- Add a custom Javascript to register page to read the invitation code from URL parameter and update invitation textbox with the correct code. This is what I intend to do if all else fails, but that will be the last resort.

Does anyone has experience with Adxstudio's invitation code function and know of a better way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In CRM go to your Send Email workflow and add a step just before you send the invitation email. What you will be required to do is encode your invitation code using a builtin encode url function or you can also use a builtin string function to find and replace any characters you want to. This is the best solution to your issue.

Comment: it is possible to use builtin function that way? Could you please point me to the relevant documentation? I couldn't find any info about that back then and went with custom workflow. @devdar

Comment: What you are required to do is in your work flow just before you use the invitation code add a step. From the drop down select Portals - Encode Invitation Code and that's the option to encode the invitation and in the next step when you are using the invitation code e.g. email select under Local Values Encode Invitation Code or what ever description you put for the step

Comment: I only have the following options under Portals: Assign Invitation Assignment, Assign Web Role, Publish Web Notifications, Send Invitation, Unassign Web Role, Update Invitation Code. May be Encode Invitation Code was added in a newer version? @devdar

Comment: @tsukumogami yes you may need to update your portal plugins to have access to these workflows